# Proving that if $8\mid (n^2+2n)$ then $2\mid n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

> Let $n\in \mathbb N$ prove that if $8\mid (n^2+2n)$ then $2\mid n$.

From the given, there exists $k\in \mathbb N$ such that $8k= (n^2+2n)$, take $k=1$, and we get $2\cdot 4 = n(n+2)$.

Now my question is, can I do the following?

$2\cdot 4 = n(n+2)\to 2\mid n(n+2)\to (2\mid n)\wedge (2\mid n+2)$ thus $2\mid n$

Comment: Can you do it? Yes. Will you have proven the statement? No, because you don't know that $k=1$.

Comment: By taking $k=1$, you are forcing $n$ to equal $2$ (or possibly $-4$, if you're allowing negative values for $n$).  But in any event, this will not give you a general proof of your result.

Comment: @GitGud, knowing that there exists such a number doesn't imply that it can be chosen?

Comment: @kuhaku Yes, it does not imply that it can be chosen. For instance if $n=6$, you get that there exists $k\in \mathbb N$ such that $8k=48$. As you can see, you can't set $k=1$.

Comment: Somehow I wonder if this question is transcribed correctly.

Comment: @quid what do you mean?

Comment: The question seems surprising to me; as a weaker condition would allow the same conclusion. For example, it would make more sense as an "if and only if."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$$n^2+2n=n(n+2)$$

But $\;n\,,\,\,n+2\;$ have the same parity and an even number divides the above, so...

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

If $n$ is odd then so is $n^2$ and also of course $n^2+2n$.

Comment: Note that this suggests a proof by contraposition.

Comment: So it's actually enough to just assume $n$ is odd then show it leads to a contradiction, thus $n$ is even.

Comment: Yes. We have $2\nmid n\Rightarrow2\nmid n^{2}+2n\Rightarrow8\nmid n^{2}+2n$ wich
is the same as $8\mid n^{2}+2n\Rightarrow2\mid n^{2}+2n\Rightarrow2\mid n$.

Answer (score 2):

if $n=2k+1$ then $n^2+2n$ is odd number..

if $n=2k$ then $n^2+2n=(2k)^2+2.(2k)=4k^2+4k=4k(k+1)$, but $k(k+1)$ is even number so that, we have done.

Comment: Why is  $k(k+1)$ an even number?

Comment: if $k$ is an even then done but if $k$ is an odd then $k+1$ is even.

Answer (score 2):

$$n^2+2n\equiv0\mod{8}\Rightarrow n^2+2n\equiv0\mod{4}\Rightarrow (n+1)^2-1\equiv0\mod{4}$$

$$\Rightarrow (n+1)^2\equiv1\mod{4}\Rightarrow n+1\equiv1\mod{2}\Rightarrow n\equiv0\mod{2}$$